# Center of Mass of two planets

Tags: astronomy

The formula for calculating the center of mass is

$$ r_{center} = \frac{m_1 \cdot r_1 + m_2 \cdot r_2}{m_1+m_2} $$

Why can't I use it to calculate the barycentre of two planets?

[image]

I understand how to use ratios to approach this problem.

$$ \frac{r_1}{r_2} = \frac{m_1}{m_2} $$ 
$$ r_1 = \frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\cdot (d_{Sun->Earth}) $$

However, I do not understand why I can not use the $r_{center}$ formula.

Comment: You can use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the center of mass formula.

Set the origin of your coordinate system at the center of the Earth, then $\vec{r}_1 = \vec{0}$ and $\vec{r}_2 = d$ and $$r_{center} = \frac{m_1r_1+m_2r_2}{m_1+m_2} = \frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2} \cdot d$$
as you have as well.

Comment: That makes sense - thank you a lot! Could you also help me with this question: If I now want to calculate the velocity of the sun orbiting arount r_center. Why did they use the circumference of the earth * pi / circulation period of the earth? Is it the same for the sun? I don't get it.

Comment: That's an application of $v=\frac{s}{t}$, but that's the velocity on the surface of a rotating sphere not around $r_{center}$. You might want to consider asking a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much again, pfnuesel; +1 and checked as answer